# Continuity and Continuity in total variation of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity

Consider a probability measure $\nu$ defined on a finite discrete set $X$.

We should endow the discrete set with discrete topology. Therefore, by property of discrete topology, we know that $\nu$ is continuous.

A sequence of probability measures $\nu_n$ converges in total variation if

$\sup\bigg\{\int_Xf(x)\nu_n(dx)-\int_Xf(x)\nu(dx)\bigg\}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

I know that a measure is continuous in total variation if this measure converges in total variation. However, does the continuity of a measure imply the continuity in total variation?

My guess is that this holds as we are dealing with a measure on a finite discrete set, therefore compact, the function is not only continuous but also uniformly continuous.

I am also wondering the following. As previously said, a function defined on a discrete topological space is continuous whatever the arrival set is. I am wondering how is this definition related to the situation of setwise continuity.

Thank you for your help.